# How to zoom google map using my OWN BUTTON in android studio?

Tags: android, google-maps, button, zooming

I am currently creating a simple android application with google map fragment.

I know the power of it's default buttons (**zoomin, out, current location and compass**) but I want to create my `OWN ZOOM BUTTON`. The problem is I can't seem to find a simple tutorial that best explains my issue, and another problem is I only have a ***limited time to use internet connection***, so I dont have plenty of time for research.

Comment: Do a relative layout with your map fragment and a button placed wherever you want relative to that fragment. Make sure to the button below the map in the xml for z axis sake. Set an onclicklistener for your button that changes the zoom level.

Comment: Yes sir, I can add button above google map fragment. I can also add onclickListener on it, but the problem is WHAT CODE do I have to add? I don't have any idea, sir please help me, I just badly needed it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adapt the following into your click functions. Some minor changes may be needed as you have not posted any of your map code.

The number 15 is the zoom level. Assuming you have a plus and minus button you will need to add or subtract 1 to an integer value to keep track of the zoom level. You will have to do checks too in regards to max and min zoom levels using an if statement as the map can only zoom in or out to a certain number.

`lat, lng` is the latitude and longitude you like to zoom to

```
        LatLng pos = new LatLng(lat, lng);
        CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(pos, 15);
        mMap.moveCamera(update);
```

Looking at the documentation https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/CameraUpdateFactory#zoomIn()

There is a simpler way using

```
map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomIn());

map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomOut());
```

by a level of 1

Answer (score 0):

You should really read [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/views) doc. If you have limited connection time you may consider using a `SeekBar` for the zoom. It's quite easy.

```
SeekBar seekBar = new SeekBar(this);
seekBar.setMax((int) (mapFragment.getMap().getMaxZoomLevel()));

seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
        mapFragment.getMap().animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(progress));
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the replies fellas. Now I find my way on zooming google map using a button. I just add setOnClickListener to the button and use the animate camera...

Code goes like this:

```
// ---CODE FOR ZOOM IN--- //
    Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomIn());
        }
    });
```

I just have to change  **mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.`zoomIn`());** to **mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.`zoomOut`());** for ZOOM OUT...

Thanks guys! Hope this helps for future questions!

Happy coding!

^_^